# How to make ListView Scrollable in flutter

Tags: flutter

Newbie here. I have managed to implement a ListView that simply displays images. However the ListView isn't scrollable. I have attempted to wrap it in SingleChildScrollView, have added physics to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics and also tried removing Expand widgets from the layout. What am I missing?

LAYOUT

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 6,
      ),
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: ref.onValue,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData &&
              !snapshot.hasError &&
              snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
            lists.clear();
            DataSnapshot dataValues = snapshot.data.snapshot;
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataValues.value as Map;
            values.forEach((key, values) {
              lists.add(values);
            });

            return new ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: lists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 2, 2, 2),
                      elevation: 20,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          String imageurl = lists[index]["image"];
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => FullScreenImageViewer(
                                  imagurl: imageurl,
                                ),
                              ));
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 400,
                            child: Image(
                              image:
                                  NetworkImage(lists[index]["image"]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }


          return Container();

        },
      ),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property within listView() that tells it which irection the overflow is so as to scroll. Set it to

```
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
```

Comment: Thank you @freddy oneya. This worked without me changing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `single child scroll view`, i believ the problem here is because you are using a `column` and the `listview` is not expanding to the whole screen. If you want to make sure the `listview` occupy the all the space remaining you can use the `Flex` and `expanded widget`.

`Flex` can work like a `column or row` depending on which direction you are providing it with. anything that is placed here behave exactly like when they is placed in the column or row except for `Expanded`, as they fill the remainning space.

I've changed your code a bit here to accomodate the Flex and Expanded widget (you just need to readd your logic and the streambuilder to make it work)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
    const SizedBox(
      height: 6,
    ),
    Expanded(
      // Change the children to stream builder if neccesary
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                elevation: 20,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // ACTION HERE
                  },
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ]),
);
```